# Using custom characters in Super Smash Bros Wii U / 3DS

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I can modify some attributes and special moves of the characters, but how can I use these customized character in the game?
Which game modes allow me to use them?

Comment: Anything I missed that you want to know about this?

Comment: Would it be better to include both versions in the question/title, so people can more easily find the information for both versions?

Comment: I changed the title, as you suggested. Tks!

Comment: Someone has changed the tags … I didn't know that it was possible 

Comment: @Tomás (it wasn't me but) the joys of high rep

Comment: I didn't know that this was the fourth game …

Comment: @Tomás in actuality any questions can have their tags changed; high-rep users and the OP can change them without review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modes allow customised characters to be selected:

- Smash (Wii U)
- Solo Smash (3DS)
- Group Smash (3DS)
- Special Smash (Wii U)
- 8-Player Smash (Wii U)
- Solo Smash Run (3DS)
- Group Smash Run (3DS)
- Classic
- Group Classic (Wii U)
- Special Orders (Wii U)
- Training
- Online With Friends

If anyone has any more to add, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent online mode from being unfair, you are limited to being able to use custom characters offline, this includes: *Smash, anything in Solo, multiplayer, and pretty much anything else that doesn't require internet*. You use these customs by pressing the button that will appear in the upper right hand corner, the fire should turn blue, and if you have customs for a character set when you pick them there should be a menu for you to choose a different set of customs you created.
P.S (Stats are also carried in the battle)

Comment: Like indeed said, this option applies to the 3DS version too?

Comment: Yes, it does work for the 3DS as well.

Comment: Also, indeed is right, I forgot about online with friends.

Comment: Got it …! I have to look for the right upper button and toggle "Custom Fighters" to "ON", in the game modes that show this button in the Characters Select screen …  the fire you said is the background color of the characters' pictures … Thanks!

Comment: @LumaForSmash Could I recommend changing your wording? There are actually a lot of offline modes that don't allow customisations, ie Stadium modes.

Comment: Your welcome, don't hesitate to ask more questions.